# Register all classes from base on up in Castle Windsor using Fluent interface

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I have an abstract base class `Search`.  An abstract class `IndexedRepositorySearch` descends from `Search`.  An abstract class `FacetSearch` descends from `IndexedRepositorySearch`.  Concrete classes `IngredientFacetSearch` and `RecipeFacetSearch` descend from `FacetSearch`.

Currently we're registering everything that descends from `Search` with Castle Windsor as follows:

```
AllTypes.FromAssembly(assembly)
        .BasedOn<Search.Search>()
        .WithServiceBase()
        .WithServiceSelf()
        .LifestyleTransient()
        .AllowMultipleMatches()
```

When we then call

```
_container.ResolveAll<FacetSearch>(new { searchInput = input, searchResults });
```

It does not resolve anything from the container.  When I put a breakpoint on the container after everything has been registered and check `AllComponents` in the debugger, I see both `IngredientFacetSearch` and `RecipeFacetSearch`, but they each only have two Services associated with them: their self and `Search`, their base.  Which you would expect given that they registered with `.WithServiceBase()` and `.WithServiceSelf()`.

So the question is how to get them to resolve by calling `ResolveAll<FacetSearch>()`?

I'm sure it's something simple but I'll be darned if I can find it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had a simliar problem to this, but only needed to register the first base which was abstract. I solved it using `WithServiceSelect` but wrapped it up into an extension method to be used so:

```
AllTypes.FromAssembly(assembly)
        .BasedOn<Search.Search>()
        .WithServiceLastAbstractBase(),
```

The definition of the extension method is:

```
public static BasedOnDescriptor WithServiceLastAbstractBase(this BasedOnDescriptor basedOn)
{
    return basedOn.WithServiceSelect(selectLastAbstractBase);
}

private static IEnumerable<Type> selectLastAbstractBase(Type type, Type[] basetypes)
{
    var baseType = type;

    do
    {
        baseType = baseType.BaseType;
    } while (baseType != null && !baseType.IsAbstract);

    if (baseType == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("There are no abstract base types for: " + type);
    }

    return new [] { baseType };
}
```